# How do I insert a combobox into a winform through code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm just a beginner at VB.NET...
I want to be able to insert a combobox control onto my form through code but I'm not sure how.  Google doesn't seem to answer.

Something along the lines of (I have no idea)
Me.AddControl("Combobox")

I would obviously then need to set the properties to setup the position/size etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its simplest form:

```
Dim cbo As New ComboBox()
' set Location and whatever else is needed '
cbo.Visible = true
Me.Controls.Add(cbo)
```

If you don't want the `ComboBox` directly inside the Form, but perhaps inside a Panel control, you just need to replace `Me` with a variable referring the intented parent control:

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(cbo)
```